# ubuntu 14.04 how to upgrade to scipy 14.0 from 13.3

Tags: python, scipy, installation

I have a blank ubuntu server 14.04 with python 2.7.6 and numpy 1.8.2.

The scipy version is 13.3.

How do I correctly install or upgrade to scipy 14.0? Without breaking the system? I tried `sudo pip install --upgrade scipy` but it produces errors.

Can I use a package manager? - Not very familiar with Linux.

Thank you

Comment: well `without breaking the system` is the hardest part here ;). If you need the latest version of scientific packages, the ubuntu repositories won't fit your need. You could think about moving to `anaconda`. A similar approach would be using `virtualenvs` and install all the packages with pip in your virtualenv. A third one is using `pip install --user scipy`. I would recommend avoiding `sudo pip install` whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

To install with `pip`, you'll need to install the build dependencies first with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-scipy
```

Similarly, if you're going to install `matplotlib` you'll need `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib` before installing with `pip`.

If you check the error when you `pip install scipy`, you'll see there's missing header files (".h" files). That's a hint about needing build dependencies.